# Angular TypeError: name.replace is not a function for bs-popover

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, popover

I'm new to angular and keep getting the following error in the console TypeError: name.replace is not a function. I'm not sure what's exactly causing it, but it seems to be caused by the bs-popover and maybe something to do with the snake_case?

The part I don't understand is why if bs-popover is used throws the error for using popover in the textbox, but rest of the application runs fine and doesn't throw the error.

Do anyone know what is the cause of this error message and a potential fix?

[image]

Html:

```
<input class="form-control" ng-model="chequeValue.BankName" name="BankName" 
ng-required='true'  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title=" {{chequeValue.BankName}}" data-unique="1" data-auto-close="1" data-placement="top" data-content-template="popover-tmpl.html" data-title="Name" data-html="true" bs-popover>
```

Comment: `TypeError: name.replace is not a function. I'm not sure what's exactly causing it` you're trying to run `.replace` and it's not a function. and what is `bs-popover` ?

Comment: this error is coming from your javascript, post your code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer to my question. Instead of using angular-strap for popover it is better to use bootstrap popover from ui-bootstrap.

```
<input class="form-control" ng-model="chequeValue.BankName" popover='{{chequeValue.BankName}}' data-placement="top" title=" {{chequeValue.BankName}}" popover-trigger="focus" popover-auto-close="outsideClick" popover-placement="top" popover-title="Drawee Bank Name">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have spaces in an angular expression

```
title=" {{chequeValue.BankName}}"
```

I'm not sure if that is the problem though. Look further at the documentation and update to uib-popover

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#popover